# "Downgrading" module to dev branch without drush

Tags: commerce

Due to some 'interesting' hosting choices by my predecessor, I'm stuck managing a dedicated server without SSH access -- FTP only. It's rough, in a lot of ways.

I have a highly customized Commerce Kickstart site where I need to include the Commerce UPS module, which requires the 2.x-dev branch instead of the recommended stable.

Short of switching to a new server provider, anyone have a solution to downgrade without Drush?

Comment: Disable the module and any modules that depend on it.  Uninstall via the UI, manually rename the modules folder (in case quick revert is needed), download the dev module via UI or manually with FTP.  Run update.php

Comment: Going from latest stable to dev is actually an upgrade, not a downgrade. I don't think Drush can even reliably automate a downgrade so if you had to actually do a downgrade it would be a manual process.

Comment: @PatrickRyan Via the UI uninstaller, it requires me to uninstall five other modules (with dependents of their own) before uninstalling the target module. This seems like a huge hassle -- is that just the way it is?

Comment: @Sam, you could also put the site in maintainence mode, then replace the ups module folder with the -dev version, run update.php and should be fine. Backup the DB first in case you need to restore. More risky but will probably work as well considering there's only the 2.x and 2.x-dev versions of that module, it's a fairly standard upgrade process.